# Adding a timing delay to Jquery.each

Tags: jquery, arrays, each, settimeout, delay

I'd like to run this array through the jQuery.each function and add a delay in-between each iteration, creating a pause in between each word appending to the div. I've seen other similar questions answered using setTimeout but I have been unsuccessful applying that to my code.

https://jsfiddle.net/samseurynck/7xw9ujjh/2/

```
var arr = ["one ", "two ", "three ", "four ", "five "];

function myFunction() {
  jQuery.each(arr, function(index, value) {
    $(".testBox").append('<p class="box">' + value + '</p>');
    console.log('yes');
  });
}

myFunction();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a counter and use `setTimeout()` method:

```js
var arr = ["one ", "two ", "three ", "four ", "five "];

function myFunction() {
  var count = 0;
  jQuery.each(arr, function(index, value) {

    setTimeout(function() {
      $(".testBox").append('<p class="box">' + value + '</p>');
      console.log('yes');
    }, count * 1000)
    count++;
  });
}

myFunction();
```

```css
.testbox {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}

p {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="testBox">
  <p class="box">

  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Further: would it be possible to then run this through a loop to run myFunction(); 10x?

Comment: @samseurynck, you're welcome. I'm glad it works. I don't understand the what you're trying to achieve further. Can you please explain a bit more or make an http://jsfiddle.net example based on what you have now?

Comment: I would like to run the function, myFunction(), multiple times until the text from the array fills up the entire window. I have been guessing that the best way to do that is to run the function through a loop, so that the "one" "two" "three" "four" array is appended over and over again, with delay from myFunction() intact. Does that make more sense?

Comment: So far I have this, which isn't exactly what I want since the array is not appending in order like it was before. https://jsfiddle.net/samseurynck/yk06Lv0g/1/

Comment: So you want to have 10 of ones, 10 of two's and so on and with delay between every ones, every twos etc? Or do you want to repeat one ... five 10 times?

Comment: The result I want would look like this: onetwothreefourfiveonetwothreefourfiveonetwothreefourfiveonetwothreefourfiveonetwothreefourfiveonetwothreefourfiveonetwothreefourfiveonetwothreefourfiveonetwothreefourfiveonetwothreefourfive (ten iterations)

Comment: Ok. Now I understand. I think this is what you need https://jsfiddle.net/yk06Lv0g/2/. Just move the loop inside the function, before the `.each()` method. Also, if you want to go 10 times, then you will have to init the `var i = 0;`

Comment: Ah, that's it! Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `index` to increment the delay timer for `setTimeout()`

```
var arr = ["one ", "two ", "three ", "four ", "five "];

function myFunction() {
  var $box = $(".testBox"),// cache container to avoid dom search each iteration
    delay = 500; //time in ms

  jQuery.each(arr, function(index, value) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $box.append('<p class="box">' + value + '</p>');
      console.log('yes');
    }, index * delay)

  });
}

myFunction();
```

**[fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/7xw9ujjh/3/)**

Answer (score 0):

Just use the index for the timeout. Example with 1 second in between:

```
var arr = ["one ", "two ", "three ", "four ", "five "];

function myFunction() {
  jQuery.each(arr, function(index, value) {
    setTimeout(function(){
        $(".testBox").append('<p class="box">' + value + '</p>');
        console.log('yes');
    }, index*1000)
  });
}

myFunction();
```

Answer (score 0):

Without adding a new variable to count the iteration, just use the `index` param

```
var arr = ["one ", "two ", "three ", "four ", "five "];

function myFunction() {
 jQuery.each(function(index, value) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $(".testBox").append('<p class="box">' + value + '</p>');
      console.log('yes');
    }, 1000 * index)
  });
}

myFunction();
```